# PCB-To-Cable connector for power and bus line

Tags: pcb-design, connector

My current design has

- Power cable: 3 pair (max 2A)
- Bus cable: 4 pair and shielded
- Distance: ~1-20m between the slave PCBs

[image: connector]

I am having trouble finding a suitable connector for the PCB and cable

For the power supply I am looking at

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-terminal-blocks/7901092/ and
https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/idc-connectors/5066904/

with the screw I would be more flexible and I do not need a connector on the cable. With the 'Stelvio' I have a clean click connection.

How should I handle the BUS cable? Previously I used https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-headers/7620872/ with https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-connector-housings/8201478/, but the mounting on the cable was not as easy as I thought and after multiple connects/disconnects the contact was a little loose.
Alternativley I looked at https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-headers/1650532/. I do not want to use a standard DSUB because of the size and the unused pins.

Are there standard header/housings for PCB-To-Cable? I filtered the RS and Mouser catalog, but was overwhelmed by the amount of connectors

Comment: we'll need a lot more info on the bus itself; "shielded" doesn't tell us anything about necessary bandwidth, impedance, number of times it will be reconnected... There can't be a "standard", because the requirements vary *a lot*.

Comment: the bus is CANopen